# Community resources for the Maude Language

Tags: logic-programming

Where do I go for interactive help when learning the [Maude Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maude_system)?

I've found books, tutorials, and webpages with excellent instruction. I can't find any sort of interaction such as an IRC channel, active mailing list, or stack exchange (There is [such a list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/maude-help/) but it gets one or two messages a month.)

What other interpersonal resources exist for this language?

Comment: The mailing-lists from http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/mailing-lists.html are the way to go.

Comment: Stack overflow serves many niche languages, so why not Maude too?

Answer (score 0):

I created the channel #maude on freenode, let's lurk there and turn it into an active community.

Maude is a nice language.